# BlackBerry Field Event not Firing?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have created a button in my Screen constructor, but when I click on the button, my event is not executing, why could that be

My code is:

```
public myScreen(){
    _startPlayingButton = new ButtonField("Play/pause");


            _startPlayingButton.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

                public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
                    try {
                        // If the START button was pressed, begin playback
                        if (field == _startPlayingButton) {
                            // The player does not exist, we must initialize it
                            if (result) {
                                System.out.println("Result1" + result);
                                if (_player == null) {
                                    // Create a stream using the remote file.
                                    _source = new ShoutcastStream(_urlField.getText());

                                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(
                                            new Runnable() {
                                                public void run() {
                                                    // Update the player status
                                                    // _playStatusField.setText("Started");
                                                }
                                            });

                                    // Create and run the player's thread
                                    _playerThread = new PlayerThread();
                                    if (_playerThread != null) {
                                        _playerThread.start();
                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println("PlayerThread is null.");
                                    }
                                }
                                // The player already exists, simply resume it
                                else {
                                    _player.start();
                                }
                                result = false;

                            } else {
                                // Acquire the UI lock
                                System.out.println("Result2" + result);


                                 UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new
                                  Runnable() { public void run() { 


                                 ("Stopped"); } });
                                  }
                                 });
                                // Destroy the Player and streams
                                destroy();
                                result = true;
                            }
                        }
                        // If the STOP button was pressed:

                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                        errorDialog(ioe.toString());
                    } catch (MediaException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }

                }
            });
            add(_startPlayingButton);
}
}
```

Comment: How did you understand that it's not fired?

Comment: i debugg it ,it is not printing my Sys outs?

Comment: Could check that you don't set another change listener for this button

Comment: yes,i haven't implemented any FieldChangeListener for my screen

Comment: Your question is badly formatted, contains lots of error. `startPlayingButton.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
   public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
    System.out.println("Event fired.");
   }
  });` - check if this code works on your simulator. You have to update your question, and remove unnecessary codes. And if you are using Eclipse IDE then format your code by pressing `Ctrl-A` and `Ctrl-Shift-F`.

Comment: Codes related to initialization of Player instance, streaming media file, or pushing a new screen to display stack are not actually related to the problem you mentioned. So you can remove those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this:

```
 _startPlayingButton = new ButtonField("Play/pause")
{
    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) 
    {
        fieldChangeNotify(1);
        return true;
    }
};
```